# Wordpress Custom Query shows only two post

Tags: wordpress

My custom query shows only 2 post, My post_ids in the array are correct and I've changed the number of $posts_per_page several times but still no luck. Any Suggestion will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

    $paged                  = get_query_var("paged") ? get_query_var("paged") : 1;
    $posts_per_page         =  5;
    $post_ids               = array( 156, 151, 154, 157, 1, 15);
    $custom_q               = new WP_Query (array(
                                    'post__in'      => $post_ids,
                                    'orderby'       => 'post__in',
                                    'paged'         => $paged
                                ));
    while($custom_q->have_posts()){
        $custom_q->the_post();
        ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
        <?php
    }
    wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Comment: you might have another filter / hook  somewhere that alter the query ? like `pre_get_post` ? also what happens if you take down the `paged` argument ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding  $posts_per_page =  5; in the WP_Query array has solved my problem.

```
<?php

$paged                  = get_query_var("paged") ? get_query_var("paged") : 1;
$post_ids               = array( 156, 151, 154, 157, 1, 15);
$custom_q               = new WP_Query (array(
                                'post__in'      => $post_ids,
                                'orderby'       => 'post__in',
                                'paged'         => $paged,
                                'posts_per_page'=>'2'
                            ));
while($custom_q->have_posts()){
    $custom_q->the_post();
    ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
    <?php
}
wp_reset_query();

?>
```